# Does "overseee" mean "one who is being overseen by the overseer"?

Tags: meaning

When I search for the word *overseee* in Google books, almost all links are typos of the verb *to oversee*, which in itself looks amazing to me. (Books rarely have such silly typos.) And only one reference among hundreds there is for the meaning I expected. (see subject)

So does the word *overseee* actually mean *the opposite of overseer*?

And the secondary question is *what makes people to mistype this particular word so frequently*? I search like that a lot, and usually a search for some typo doesn't fetch that many results like that. OED and Merriam-Webster don't have this word.

Comment: I would use "overseen" if I needed the opposite of "overseer". "Overseee" leaves me asea.

Comment: I will not accept any word with three consecutive e's as English.

Comment: I can only find one other word with three trailing _e_'s: _skweee_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skweee

Comment: It could simply be a particularly difficult typo for proofreaders to spot.

Comment: @MattSamuel go tell that to the IEEE.

Comment: 'overseee' is not a word. Or rather it would only be perceived as a humorous nonceword. '-ee' is a foreignism and isn't necessarily productive in English. By analogy you could use it with anything but that doesn't mean anybody else has or that it will sound good.

Comment: If neither Merriam-Webster nor the OED have the word maybe -it isn't a word?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not. Though it is not an explicit rule, there is a very strong convention against triple letter words in English. In fact, there are only about twenty such words (eg. See [this stub](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_words_in_English_with_tripled_letters)).

The word you're looking for is "overseen". Eg, the overseee  is the overseen.

Comment: The convention can't be all that strong, or really a convention at all, if I can spend a whole life on this planet without ever so much as hearing about it. Are you sure it exists? You yourself have provided examples to the contrary. I am most very confused right now.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - It is worth noting that all of the examples are either onomatopoeia, proper names, or suffixed words (and only 3 distinct variations of those).  English does not like triple letters.  (In part I suspect that this is purely practical -- triple letters (especially with, eg, "eee") are hard to accurately read and transcribe.

Comment: @HotLicks you say that like there's a wealth of languages out there that do like triple letters. Care to name a hundred or so? Because otherwise that's a rather pointless thing to say, innit. Russian has more words than English but exactly *one* with three consecutive Еs: *длинношеее*. Clearly, by comparison, English is clinically obsessed with trippling its Es.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - Well, I don't know any Russian, Chinese, or Hindu.  I know a smattering of Spanish and just a touch of Norwegian.  I chose to write about what I know.  Do you have an objection to that?

Comment: @RegDwigнt given that there are about 250,000 non-specialized words in the English language, and of those, only about 20 (that's 0.008%) include the same letter three times, it is self-evident that the convention exist. That you are not aware of it is irrelevant -- 'convention' means 'the way in which something is usually done'.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I actually studied this matter (English vs. Russian word counts), and I typically couldn't find the Russian equivalents of English worlds, and not the way around. I am convinced that English has way more words for basic concepts compared to Russian. But Russian words have a lot more inflection forms, and if you count all of them then maybe Russian will have more words in total. So the answer depends on how you count.